# using jQuery with React JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Hi I was just testing jQuery with React JS for some reason. But facing an issue like this.
when I try this in console

```
$(".cities-container select").val()
```

I got this

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val is not a function
```

But when I try this

```
$(".cities-container select")
```

I got whole select element in the console, means jQuery is working but not .val method

any suggestions...?

Comment: When you did $(".cities-container select"), what was the output?

Comment: `$` is a shortcut for the document query selector in the browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: I got Whole HTML of select element

Comment: @h_a86 Can you paste the output here?

Comment: <select>   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>   <option value="saab">Saab</option>   <option value="opel">Opel</option>   <option value="audi">Audi</option> </select>

Comment: @OluwafemiSule where did you get that info?

Comment: @pwolaq https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
$(".cities-container select")[0].value
```

This should resolve your problem.

Comment: This is what you tried right $(".cities-container select")[0].value?

Comment: Yes I used cities

Comment: @h_a86 what is the console.log for this $(".cities-container select")[0]

Comment: down voting the answer is so wrong here.We are trying to help.

Comment: I didn't, believe me

Comment: What did you get for the console.log statement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147349/discussion-between-h-a86-and-vivekn).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery selectors often return an array of elements. Try getting the first element, like so:

```
$(".cities-container select")[0].val()
```

Or using the `.get()` method:

```
$(".cities-container select").get(0).val()
```

Answer (score 0):

You get `$` as an alias for `document.querySelector` when jQuery isn't active. This means using `$(".cities-container select").value` instead of jQuery's `$(".cities-container select").val()`.

Check that the jQuery library is loaded by checking that jQuery version isn't `undefined` (see snippet for an example) or by trying to make a new jQuery instance in the console using the `jQuery` function.

References:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    var selectOpt = $("#select-opt").val();

    console.log(selectOpt);
  }
);

var jQueryNotActivated = $().jquery == undefined; // jquery alias isn't active

if(jQueryNotActivated) {
  // In chrome, $ is alias for document.querySelector
  var selectOptwithdQS = $("#select-opt");
  console.log(selectOptwithdQS.value);  
}
```

```html
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
</head>


<body>
  <select id="select-opt">
    <option val="bus">Bus</option>
    <option val="box">Box</option>
  </select>
</body>
```